# Log reader w. save option

Tags: logging

I'm missing a simple log file reader that has the possibility of "remembering" the log-files of my various websites. I'd really like the possibility of opening all 5-10 log-files relating to a certain website in one click, making it easy to switch between log-files of different sites. Nothing fancy, just something like being able to save & load a bunch of files into the log-file-viewer

cheers
Ask

Comment: `multitail` https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8414/how-to-have-tail-f-show-colored-output

Comment: thanx, that looks nice. But I'm on a windows environment  :-/

Comment: Website for it says that it works also in Windows using cygwin...

Comment: I'll give it a shot then  :)